# Serve same content regardless of get request in SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: network-programming, simplehttpserver

I am trying to run a python-simpleHTTP webserver that will serve the same content regardless of the request that is received. Currently when I try and do so, I get a file no found 404.

I have tried to override `def list_directory(self, path):` and make it pass regardless, since I thought this was the class that failed if the request isn't on the server. Is this the correct to override, or is there more to do?

I put the list_directory method in MyHandler, here is the simple starting HTTP server code.

```
Handler = MyHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: `SocketServer.TCPServer` is not a class from Twisted. Are you sure this is a question about Twisted?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The source code is extremely helpful  http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py

Instead of overriding list_directory, you can override send_head() inside of your handler with something like this:

```
    def send_head(self):
        """
        This sends the response code and MIME headers.
        """
        path = THE FILE YOU WANT TO SERVE NO MATTER WHAT
        f = open(path)
        self.send_response(200)
        ctype = self.guess_type(path)
        self.send_header("Content-type", ctype)
        self.end_headers()
        return f
```